# How do I change the text color of a file with a certain VCS status?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1. I can't seem to find the right setting to change the color of the text in the project view. Specifically the color that is used for a file that has been moved under a version-controlled project. As you can see in the image below, the text color on the Darcula background color is *really* difficult to read.

Is it possible to configure the color used for files with a specific status?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File status colors can be changed here:

[image: file color]

It's possible that you are using some non-standard editor color scheme that is not inherited from one of the default schemes.

Comment: Thank you for this! You're correct, I had a custom Scheme setup. I had to switch back to the Darcula scheme, and reconfigure some font settings. I was then able to see the options listed in the File Status section.